# What is the grammatical role of "that" in "the percentage that + clause"?

Tags: grammar

I am confused with the role of "that" and the clause that follows in the passage below. Is the "that-clause" grammatical here? If no, how should it be put in a grammatical manner? If yes, what is the grammatical role of "that" (like complementizer, relative pronoun? ) and how to analyze the structure of the clause?

"[...] In 2005, Iceland’s pay gap showed that women were, on average, still being paid only 64.15% of what men earned. So, on the thirtieth anniversary of the Women’s Day Off, women organized another strike and left work at 2:08 p.m., shortening their workday by the exact percentage ***that*** *their salaries were lower than men’s.* In 2016, women in Iceland again left work early, this time at 2:38 p.m. [...]"

Your help and clarification are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not how I would express it. I would say *the exact percentage by which their salaries were lower than men's*.

However, "by which" is somewhat formal, and people will often prefer to turn it round, and leave the preposition at the end of the relative clause:

> the man to whom I was talking -> the man [who/whom/that] I was talking to

If you do that in this case, you get

> the exact percentage that their salaries were lower than men's by.

which is nearly what you quoted. But they left out the final "by" - I suspect that is because of the "by" just before what I quoted.

So I would say that the text is grammatically defective; but *that* is (as it often is) a complementizer in a relative clause without explicit relative pronoun.

Comment: But what about the sentences like "If you helped boost sales, for example, what was the percentage that the sales increased?" , or " To find the percentage that the original price decreased, use the following relation", or "I need to create a measure to calculate the percentage that the total Sales value increased " from the internet? I still could not figure out how to treat "that" and how to analyze the structure that it takes in terms of their syntactic roles....

Comment: @StephenLai: I find both those examples defective, because they are missing a "by", just like the original sentence. My analysis applies to them too.

Comment: IMHO part of the problem here is that a lot of native speakers have been erroneously told that you "can't end a sentence in a preposition," so they delete the trailing "by" and assume the result will still make sense.

Comment: @Kevin: that might be a factor, but I don't think it's the main one. I think that by the time you get to the end of that rather complex sentence, you've probably forgotten what the construction was.